# How to create a vector of sequences based on a vector of lengths

Tags: r, loops

I'm hoping to create a vector of sequences (1:n) of varying lengths.  I'm hoping to use another vector to specify the lengths of these sequences.

For example, for the vector of lengths I have:

```
lengths <- c(10,6,4,7)
```

I'm wanting R to return:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4, etc.
```

I feel like a loop of some kind might be in order but I can't seem to get it to work.  Maybe something like this:

```
out <- NULL
for (i in length(lengths)){
    out[i] <- 1:lengths[i]
    }
```

I end up with this error:

Warning message:
In out[i] <- 1:lengths[i] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried your "maybe something like this" code? What does "can't seem to crack the code" mean? Do you have error messages you can share with us to help you debug?

Comment: Thanks, Scott.  I've tried to clarify the code and error a bit better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sequence(lengths)
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10  1  2  3  4  5  6  1  2  3  4  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

Comment: Can't get simpler than that - `seq_len()` is the workhorse underneath this function.

Comment: Brilliant!!  SO wins again!  Thanks, Frank.